# Is it healthy for my application to go live with Kotlin experimental features in the code?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, gradle-experimental

I am using Kotlin's experimental features, and I wonder if it will work well in the live version of the app? For example the `@Parcel` annotation in Kotlin.

Comment: "Experimental" pertains primarily to the API which is not stable and you'll have to change your code when upgrading Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how comfortable you are with releasing an unfinished experimental feature with your codebase. There is the possibility that there are still bugs or the feature has not fully been tested, hence the reason it is in experimental status.

That being said, if the feature is included in the Kotlin documentation found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#experimental-mode), then you can assume the feature will work to a certain extent. However, you must be ready to make updates as necessary because this feature is still in active development. Be sure to keep your Kotlin version up-to-date so that you are receiving the latest updates to experimental features if you are releasing these with your production application.